# angular js working perfect in phoneGap or browser but not woking in apk

Tags: angularjs

i  downloaded the source code from internet of a sign in application using angular, its working perfect with phonegap or in browser but is not displaying anything when i have created an APK.I have created apk using cordova as well as ionic  from win7 CLI.

Steps i followed:
1.installed Git
2.installed node 
3. installed ionic 
4. JRE
5. SDK
 and then following commands 
1.ionic start myApp
2. cd myApp
3. ionic platform android
4. ionic emulate android 
5. ionic run android

i replaced the  index file and js file in www with my file.
please tell me where am i doing wrong?

Comment: Does the problem occur when running `ionic serve`? Do you get 404 errors on anything?

Comment: yes working perfect on ionic serve.
M i missing something in creating APK